# Openshift and django deployment

Tags: django, deployment, openshift

I am trying to deploy a django project on openshift for testgin puposes. I tried to use this process described [here](https://www.openshift.com/get-started/django) but can't seem to be able to work it out. I successfully create my app using

```
rhc app create django python-2.6
```

But when I try to add the git it gives me the following error

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount parent )
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

At creation time, Openshift should create a directory `django` with a skeleton WSGI application, and git folder containing the remotes needed so you can just `git push` its contents to the Openshift app repo.

If you are working in another directory, you have to `git init` and then add the remotes to Openshift.

Comment: how it worked for me....I had to add -t in the command that is:
rhc app create django -t python-2.7 and it worked fine. I don't know though why they have it without the -t switch in their git page